# Slide All except Div with ID

Tags: jquery

How to I write this

Slide All Div up except the div with id 'div1'

```
$(acc).children('div:not('div1')').slideUp();
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(acc).children('div:not(#div1)').slideUp();
```